# Enable Coldfusion ORM per component

Tags: orm, coldfusion, components, cfc

I've started using ORM in Coldfusion 9, but I'm running into an issue in which I've got a CFC that is set to `persistant=true` so that when I run `myCFC.init()` the default values of the properties are assigned - but I don't want to use this CFC with ORM.

The problem is that Coldfusion throws the error **"Table myCFC defined for cfc myCFC does not exist."**

Is there a way I can get my application to ignore certain CFCs? Or only pay attention to specific CFCs, other than `persistant=true`

Alternatively, can I get my default property values to take effect without making the component persistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, can I get my default property values to take effect without making the component persistent?

Yes, just set them in your **init()** method.

```
<cfcomponent name="person" persistent="false" output="false">

 <cfproperty name="gender"><!--- Non-persistent CFC: you can't set a default here --->

 <cffunction name="init" output="false>
  <cfset variables.gender = "m"><!--- Set the default here --->
 </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

You would also need to do this in your persistent CFCs for any complex or dynamic value defaults (e.g. an array or the current date), since you can only set simple default values (e.g. a literal string or integer) in property declarations.

```
<cfcomponent name="person" persistent="true" table="persons" output="false">

 <cfproperty name="gender" default="m"><!---Persistent CFC, so this simple default will be set --->
 <cfproperty name="dateCreated"><!---You can't set a default dynamic date value --->

 <cffunction name="init" output="false>
  <cfset variables.dateCreated= Now()><!--- Set the current datetime here --->
 </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: I suppose I should have thought of this, as you said I have to do this for more complex values anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any code you place between your opening  and the first  will be executed. I'm assuming your using CFproperty tags to set you defaults. Instead, use this structure:

```
<cfcomponent name="aCFC">

    <!---
    || Psuedo Constructor code: this code runs when the object is created.
    ||--->

    <cfset defaultVar_1 = "default value">
    ...etc

    <cffunction name="firstFunction">
        ...
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: That example doesn't scope the variable defaultVar_1 to anything. Also using properties with accessors=true gives me getters and setters, which your approach doesn't give. You answer also wouldn't solve the issue of the fact that I don't want every CFC in the application to use ORM, would it?

Comment: First, its an example, so you can scope the variable however you choose. Second, This CFC doesn't use ORM, the reason you get the error is when you tell coldfusion a CFC is persistant is either looks for the table attribute or assumes the name of the CFC is the table name because persistance is for ORM cfc's. And no you won't get auto generated getters and setters, but you can write them yourself. My simple point is: persistant=true = ORM

Comment: persistant=true = ORM only if application.ormenabled = true. If application.ormenabled = false, then persistent=true ensures that property defaults actually get set. I want to be able to set ORM at component level, not application level, or ensure property defaults are acutally used without using persistant.

Comment: `If a component is not used as a web service, <cfproperty> only provides metadata information of the property. It does not define variables or set values that you can use in your component. However, it creates implicit setters and getters for the property in the CFC depending on whether getter/setter attributes are enabled. For details, see Implicit Get and Set Functions in Developing ColdFusion Applications.` - the docs

Comment: True, unless you set persistent =true, in whcih case, the default values are populated and used: http://cfsimplicity.com/23/using-cfproperty-to-create-default-cfc-property-values

Comment: from the same source: `The problem seems to be that CF doesn't put the properties into the variables scope until each one is assigned a value, as explained in this post by Ciarán Archer, and reported as a bug by Luis Majano. In other words we can only get it if we first set it.` - This is directly related to my last comment. The properties only exist as metadata until they are set UNLESS used in ORM or as a WebService.

Comment: So in conclusion, I can't set defaults without persistant=true or using it as webservice. So ignoring that, can I make the ORM application ignore certain CFCs?

Comment: No, Sorry. Would be useful If you could.